# Can someone help me with my react app that runs in the localhost and doesn't display anything?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/material/styles';
import { Grid, Typography, Link } from '@mui/material';

// We can use the makeStyles hook from MUI to create a custom styles object
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  root: {
    flexGrow: 1,
  },
}));

function App() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [data, setData] = useState(null); // we'll use this state variable to store the data we get from the API

  useEffect(() => {
    // This function will run when the component mounts (similar to componentDidMount in a class-based component)
    // We'll use the fetch API to get data from the API
    fetch('https://api.example.com/endpoint')
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((json) => {
        setData(json);
      });
  }, []); // We pass an empty array as the second argument to useEffect to make sure it only runs once

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Grid container spacing={3}>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          <Typography variant="h2">Hello BeyondMD!</Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid item xs={12}>
          {/* Here, we use the Link component from MUI to create a link to a PDF file */}
          <Link href="public\Resume+Template.pdf" target="_blank">
            View my resume
          </Link>
        </Grid>
        {data && (
          <Grid item xs={12}>
            {/* If we have data from the API, we can render it here */}
            <Typography variant="body1">{data.someProperty}</Typography>
          </Grid>
        )}
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Im trying to display my resume that I have put in the public and also fetch data from a free API (I dont know where though). In the end it is giving me a blank page with the localhost.

I have tried almost everything I can find online. I want it to display a line of text and my resume and also data from a free API anywhere.

Comment: Could you please check console warninng or errors.